# Assinging a static function from a class to a variable

Tags: c#

I want to be able to assign functions from classes to variables

Ex:

```
namespace test
{
    class init
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var toSingle = BitConverter.ToSingle;
            
        }
    }

}
```

**ERROR** The delegate type could not be inferred.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because there is more than one `BitConverter.ToSingle` method, you need to specify the delegate type, depending on which one you want. `var toSingle = (Func<...TODO...>)BitConverter.ToSingle`

Comment: Convience? This question has already been answered though.

Comment: My opinion: Don't do this. Simply write `BitConverter.ToSingle`. It makes it a lot clearer to someone else reading your code what you're doing. They don't have to spend time to figure out what a `toSingle` variable from somewhere else in the class does, and they don't have to realise that you have a static using if you call `ToSingle`. Ease of understanding when reading the code later trumps brevity, and (my opinion) in situations where performance isn't paramount, it also trumps minor performance gains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rather think you might want `using static` (applied to the top of the file with your other using imports, or just inside your namespace):

```cs
using static BitConverter;
```

This will allow you to simply call `ToSingle(...)` anywhere in your class.

[`using static` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier)

Alternatively, if you really want to assign it to a variable, you could potentially assign it to a delegate (here I'll use `Func`):

```cs
Func<byte[], int, float> toSingle = BitConverter.ToSingle;
```

Though this won't work if you want to use the overload that takes a `ReadOnlySpan<Bye>` because it can't be a generic parameter.

Comment: Cool, I found out about aliasing long variables the other day, didn't know you can do this! Though the delegate was my first thought.

Comment: Very helpful thank you for getting to the point and explaining it simply.

Comment: @Require Please also see my comment on the question itself for my thoughts on doing this (but that is my opinion and others may disagree, so feel free to disregard it).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar
Disregarding it would be arogant. I did read it and I agree it would be bad practice to do that now. However, I do think that simply doing `using static BitConverter` would be ideal as its both convient and easy to read (in my opinion)